# How to re-update a game?

Tags: xbox-360

I had just recently downloaded the new update for Grand Theft Auto V, but while the console was restarting the power went out and I think the update messed up. I can't play GTA online like the update was suppose to make me able to. Is there a way to re-do an update?

Comment: Mhhh, I think if you remove this update, you can re-download it (start the game, there should be the prompt). Found a short [tutorial](https://help.ea.com/article/how-do-i-remove-game-updates-from-my-xbox-360)

Comment: How would I go about removing the update?

Comment: I linked a tutorial. Klick on the word "tutorial", in my first comment.

Comment: You can either find the update in System-Console-Storage then the game your looking for or when you are in storage and have to picj a memory device just press "Y" on it to clear the cache which also can delete the update

Comment: Thanks a lot for yalls advice I think I got it updated again I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user56788 Please be sure to accept TZHX's answer if it helped you. Otherwise please indicate in some way which method worked best, you can also answer your own question with the information that worked best.

Answer (score 5):

If you go into storage management in the console settings and select the game you are interested in, you will then be able to delete the 'title update' by highlighting it, pressing X and then selecting 'delete'.  When you next start the game, it should rewownload and install it.